# Abstract algebra olympiad problem for university student

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking for abstract algebra problem book for preparring olympiad for university student, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A book is "Putnam and Beyond"

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68445-1